# unable to fire \copy command using sqlx library golang

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am unable to fire the the below Exec command using golang sql library

`db.Exec("\\COPY schema.table TO './tablename.csv' DELIMITER ','  NULL as 'null' CSV HEADER ;")`

I get exception syntax error at or near ""\COPY

If I use as below 

`db.Exec("\COPY schema.table TO './tablename.csv' DELIMITER ','  NULL as 'null' CSV HEADER ;")`

I get error like syntax error at or near "\"

I cannot fire COPY TO as command as I should be super user
pq: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file

Anyway to fire the \copy to command using sql library?

I am able to run this command successfully from shell prompt using psql

Comment: No, `\copy` is a `psql` command, not a SQL statement. The equivalent SQL statement is [`copy ...  from stdin ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. we can close this question